# Merge two or more cubic Bézier curves for optimization

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computer-science, algebraic-curves, curves

I am looking for an algorithm which can merge several cubic Bezier curves. For instance, I have a lot of cubic Bezier that are joined to form a poly-Bezier curve. The idea is to merge dynamically some of these cubic Bezier segments to one cubic Bezier in order to minimize the number of the Bézier curves.

Anyone can help me for this problem?

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 2):

In general, several Bezier curves (even two) can not be represented exactly as a single Bezier curve. So, the best you can hope for is an approximation.

I'd suggest the following approach.

Take two of your curves, say $A(t)$ and $B(t)$. Assume they are both parameterized by $t \in [0,1]$. Calculate four equally-spaced points on these two curves. These would be $P_1 = A(0)$, $P_2= A(2/3)$, $P_3 = B(1/3)$, $P_3 = B(1)$. Then calculate a Bezier curve $C(t)$ such that $C(0) = P_1$, $C(1/3) = P_2$, $C(2/3) = P_3$, $C(1) = P_4$. Then check to see whether $C$ is "close" enough to $A$ and $B$.

Once you have this basic "two-into-one" utility working, there are numerous ways to use it to combine longer strings of curves.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, it is a very good approach that will help me.
Do you think that your method is valid for all shapes?
Is it necessary to get informations about inflection points or changement of curve's direction?

Comment: There is no need to check for inflexions or changes of curvature or direction. If the original curves are more complex, then the approximation will (generally) give larger errors, so your ability to combine/merge will be less, that's all.

Comment: Ok I tried 2 complexes curves and the result was not as I expected. I am trying to merge 2 simples curves  and I will keep you informed. Thank you again.

Comment: I see the problem, the t parameter has not a liner value, in other words, these relations: C(1/3) = A(2/3) and C(2/3)=B(1/3) are not always true. For example, A(1/2) is not necessarily the midpoint of A curve.

Comment: Folks in my business would say that $A(1/2)$ is the "parametric" mid-point. But it's not the mid-point as measured by arclength. That should not matter, though. Try splitting a curve into two pieces, and then see if your code can correctly join them back into one. If it can't, then there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Hello, the algorithm works only if the initial curve is subdivised on the point corresponding to t=0.5.

Comment: But I still don't know what is the proof that C(1/3) = A (2/3) and C(2/3) = B(1/3)